# Relationship of Induction Motor Frequencies

Tags: motor, frequency, induction-motor, formula-derivation

I would like to know how the mechanical rotor frequency [Hz] can be obtained from the electrical stator frequency [Hz]? This is no homework! I have consulted several books as well as the web but could not find an exact relationship expressed as formula. I hope somebody can give advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synchronous speed of the rotor in RPM N = 120f/P where f is the frequency of the stator current and P is the number of poles.

The operating speed No = N - Ns where Ns is the slip speed.

The frequency of the rotor current fr = Ns x P/120, so fr = 0 if the slip is zero.

If the operating speed is zero, Ns = N and the frequency of the rotor current is the same as the frequency of the stator current.

Comment: Thank you Charles! According to my calculations, this confirms the equation given in my comment in alphasierra's answer assuming that there p stands for the number of pole pairs.

Answer (score 6):

$$f = \frac {P\ N_S}{120}$$

- \$f\$ = source frequency in Hz.  Your electrical stator frequency.
- P = # of three-phase pole pairs (2, 4, 6, etc.).
- \$N_S\$ = synchronous speed in rpm.

Synchronous speed at 60Hz will be:

- 3600 rpm for a 2-pole machine (2-pole/phase = 6 total poles).
- 1800 rpm for a 4-pole machine (12 total).

[image: Motor nameplate]

If we take a motor nameplate to illustrate the mechanical.

$$f_r = \frac {P\ N}{120}= \frac {4\ poles\times 1765\ rpm}{120} = 58.83Hz$$

- \$f_r\$ = mechanical rotor frequency in Hz.
- N = rotor speed in rpm.

\$f\$ and \$f_r\$ are related by slip.  For a motor to develop torque, \$f_r < f\$ and \$N < N_s\$.
$$ s = \frac {N_S - N}{N_S} = \frac {1800\ rpm - 1765\ rpm}{1800\ rpm} = 0.01944$$

Slip at rated motor load is 1.94%.  Slip and rotor speed actual depend on the load being driven with most motors having a slip between 0.5% and 5%.  Heavier the load, the larger the slip.

This is a 4-pole motor because:

$$P = \frac {120\ f}{N} = \frac {120 \times 60\ Hz}{1765\ rpm} = 4.079$$

Rounding down gives us 4-poles/phase.

Comment: On question regarding the `P` in your equations `f=(P*Ns)/120` and `fr=(P*N)/120`. In the first equation you say it is the "# of three-phase _pole pairs_" and in the second equation "4 _poles_ ×1765rpm". So, does P now stand for the number of pole pairs (e.g. 1,2,3) or the number of poles (2,4,6)?

Comment: Yes.  2 poles/phase means 6 poles for a 3 phase machine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the motor itself, and the load. When motoring the rotor frequency is always lower than the stator frequency. The difference between these two frequencies is called the slip. The amount of slip depends on the input power, the applied load, and the characteristics of the specific motor.

The equation is $$s=\frac{(n_s-n_r)}{n_s}$$
$$n_s=stator frequency$$$$n_r=rotor frequency$$

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtJoJBUSe28) should help give a simple explanation of it.

Comment: I think that the rotor frequency in your formula is not the mechanical rotary frequency. I would expect the number of pole pairs somewhere in this equation.

Comment: Could this perhaps be the equation we are looking for: s = (fs - p*fr_mech) / fs ?

Comment: It is the rotor rotational frequency. I just checked it against a textbook I have here. Not sure if I'm allowed to post screenshots of it.

Answer (score 0):

First off I know this is a very old post, but the highest rated answer to this question is a bit confusing. While the mechanical frequency they derive in hertz is technically the correct mechanical frequency, if we were to express it in hertz, we can add a bit more explanation to how we get there.

Electrical Machinery Fundamentals, Fifth Edition, by Stephen J. Chapman does a wonderful job of explaining the functionality of induction motors and I strongly recommend anyone studying motors in general to give this book a try.

**So here's what I believe represents a better explanation:**

Slip can be derived using the following equation:

$$s = \frac{n\tiny{sync}\normalsize{-n}\tiny{m}}{n\tiny{sync}}*(100)$$

where,

$$n\tiny{m}\normalsize{\text{= rotor (shaft) speed of the motor}}$$
$$n\tiny{sync}\normalsize{\text{=speed of the magnetic fields}}$$

This gives you the percentage of slip, which represents the percent **difference** between the rotational **mechanical speed of the rotor** and the rotational **frequency of the magnetic field in the stator**.

Relative to the rotation of the magnetic field, the mechanical frequency of the shaft is slower than the rotational speed of the magnetic field by the percent slip we calculated above.

$$n\tiny{m}\normalsize{\text{= rotor (shaft) speed of the motor}}$$
$$n\tiny{sync}\normalsize{\text{=speed of the magnetic fields}}$$

To calculate the frequency of the magnetic field in the rotor we use the equation:
$$f\tiny{r}\normalsize{=f\tiny{s}\normalsize{*s}}$$
where,
$$f\tiny{s}\normalsize{\text{= the frequency of the magnetic field in the stator}}$$
$$f\tiny{r}\normalsize{\text{= the frequency of the magnetic field in the rotor}}$$
$$s=slip$$

**The frequency of the magnetic field created by the current induced on the rotor is directly proportional to the the difference in rotational speed between the stator field and the mechanical rotation of the rotor.**

So, if we want to go right from stator frequency to mechanical frequency, we can use:

$$f\tiny{m}\normalsize{= f}\tiny{s}\normalsize{*(1-s)}$$

where,

$$f\tiny{m}\normalsize{\text{= the mechanical frequency of the rotor in hertz}}$$

**We can also do the following:**

To find the mechanical frequency of the rotor, we only can reorganize our original equation:
$$s = \frac{n\tiny{sync}\normalsize{-n}\tiny{m}}{n\tiny{sync}}$$
to
$$n\tiny{m}\normalsize{= n}\tiny{sync}\normalsize{-(s*n}\tiny{sync}\normalsize{)}$$
or
$$n\tiny{m}\normalsize{= n}\tiny{sync}\normalsize{(1-s)}$$

If we want to change this to hertz, we can do this by reconfiguring the equation we use to find the rotational speed of the magnetic field in the stator:

$$n\tiny{sync} = \frac{\normalsize{120*f}\tiny{s}}{\normalsize{P}}$$

to

$$n\tiny{m} = \frac{\normalsize{120*f}\tiny{m}}{\normalsize{P}}$$

and finally:

$$f\tiny{m} = \frac{\normalsize{P*n}\tiny{m}}{\normalsize{120}}$$

Where:

$$P{\text{= the number of poles in the motor}}$$

$$f\tiny{m}\normalsize{\text{= the mechanical frequency of the rotor in hertz}}$$

I hope this helps any future students who stumble upon this thread!